# XML TO CSV USING MAPPING NODE

Tags: dfdl

is it possible to convert xml data to csv using DFDL with MAPPING NODE

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just set the output domain to DFDL. The conversion to CSV is not actually performed by the Mapping node. The input message tree is constructed from the XML document by the XMLNSC parser, and the output CSV is constructed by the DFDL parser from the message tree and the model. The role of the Mapping node is to construct the output message tree.